# Congruent powers implies numbers are congruent

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, congruences

Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$, and let $m,n$ be coprime. Also, suppose $a,b$ are relatively prime to $N$, and that
$$
a^n\equiv b^n\mod{N},\ a^m\equiv b^m\mod{N}
$$
I need to show that $a\equiv b\mod{N}$. I have an attempt, just one move I am not sure about.

Since $m,n$ are coprime, then for some $m',n'\in\mathbb{Z}$, $mm' + nn' = 1$. Now, since $a^n\equiv b^n\mod{N}$, then $a^{nn'}\equiv b^{nn'}\mod{N}$. From this, I get that
$$
a^{nn'}\equiv b^{nn'}\mod{N} \Leftrightarrow a^{1-mm'}\equiv b^{1-mm'}\mod{N}
$$

$$
\Leftrightarrow a(a^{-m})^{m'} \equiv b(b^{-m})^{m'}\mod{N}
$$
Now, since $a,b$ are relatively prime to $N$, then
$$
a^m\equiv b^m\mod{N} \Rightarrow a^{-m}\equiv b^{-m}\mod{N}
$$
and therefore, again since $a,b$ are relatively prime to $N$, we can cancel them from both sides, leaving
$$
a\equiv b\mod{N}
$$

Are all the moves and derivations here correct?

Comment: A simple proof would be to use $\gcd(a^m-b^m,a^n-b^n)=a^{\gcd(m,n)}-b^{\gcd(m,n)}$.

Comment: What about my proof?

Comment: Your proof looks okay, but you could also note that $$a=a^{mm'+nn'}=\left(a^m\right)^{m'}\left(a^n\right)^{n'}\equiv\left(b^m\right)^{m'}\left(b^n\right)^{n'}=b^{mm'+nn'}=b\mod{N}$$ since $a$ & $b$ are invertible modulo $N$.

Comment: @bgins What move requires $a,b$ be invertible $\mod{N}$?

Comment: Since $mm'+nn'=1$, we know that it is likely/often the case that one of $m',n'$ is negative. Isolating negative integral powers of (powers of) $a$ and $b$ is only justified if they are invertible.

Answer (score 2):

One has $\exists u,v\in\Bbb{Z},\, um+vn=1$ as a direct consequence of $(m,n)=1$. Raising the first congruence to the power $v$ and the second to the power $u$ one gets $\pmod{N}$

$$\begin{align} a^{vn}&\equiv b^{vn}\\a^{um}&\equiv b^{um}\end{align}$$

Multiplying the two congruences together, one gets

$$a^{um+vn}=a\equiv b=b^{um+vn}\pmod{N}$$